# Issues with parsing HTML with ragel

Tags: html, parsing, html-parsing, ragel

In my project I need to extract links from HTML document.
For this purpose I've prepared ragel HTML grammar, primarily based on this work:
https://github.com/brianpane/jitify-core/blob/master/src/core/jitify_html_lexer.rl
(mentioned here: http://ragel-users.complang.narkive.com/qhjr33zj/ragel-grammars-for-html-css-and-javascript )

Almost all works well (thanks for the great tool!), except one issue I can't overcome to date:

If I specify this text as an input:

```
bbbb <a href="first_link.aspx">  cccc<a href="/second_link.aspx">
```

my parser can correctly extract first link, but not the second one.
The difference between them is that there is a space between `'bbbb'` and `'<a'`, but no spaces between `'cccc'` and `'<a'`.

In general, if any text, except spaces, exists before `'<a'` tag it makes parses consider it as content, and parser do not recognize tag opening.

Please find in this repo: https://github.com/amdei/ragel_html_sample intentionally simplified sample with grammar, aiming to work as C program ( ngx_url_html_portion.rl ).
There is also input file input-nbsp.html , which expected to contain input for the application.

In order to play with it, make .c-file from grammar:

```
ragel ngx_url_html_portion.rl
```

then compile resulting .c-file and run programm.

Input file should be in the same directory.

Will be sincerely grateful for any clue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the defined FSM is that it includes into 'content' all characters until the space. You should exclude HTML tag opening '<' from the rule. Here is the diff for illustration:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/ngx_url_html_portion.rl b/ngx_url_html_portion.rl
index ccef0ca..1f8dcf0 100644
--- a/ngx_url_html_portion.rl
+++ b/ngx_url_html_portion.rl
@@ -145,7 +145,7 @@ void copy2hrefbuf(par_t* par, u_char* p){
     );

     content = (
-      any - (space )
+      any - (space ) - '<'
     )+;

     html_space = (
```